# 저는 만지지 마십시오 meaning with context

Tags: meaning, conversation

I would like to ask you one question. 
What does the sentence mean? You can provide any context if possible.

저는 만지지 마십시오.

A. Do not touch me

B. I do not touch (something)

C. Both A and B are possible depending on the context.

I think that 저 here is topic marker not necessarily a subject so both A and B are possible. However, my Vietnamese friend said there is no context to make B right. Could you shed some light on this? If B can be right, could you show an example where it is possibe?

Comment: 저를 만지지 마십시오 would be more natural.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The -십시오 ending is a polite imperative, for polite requests and instructions. You would only use this ending when you're talking to someone else; the sentence therefore means "Do not touch me".

This wouldn't make sense if 'me' was the subject, but as you rightly say, the -는 marker doesn't have to go on subjects; it can be used for just for emphasis. So the natural translation would be something like

> Don't touch *me*.

The implication being that the speaker might not care if this person touches some other people, but they are asking the listener not to touch *them*.